# Start javaFX application from a webservice context

Tags: java, javafx, jar, spring-boot

I'd like to know how could I achieve the following situation:

I'm building a client interface and rest endpoint so I can start this interface from my website, through an API call, this client will be installed on client's machine as a service, so the API will be running all the time. It runs on an embedded server provided by Spring Boot framework. The interface is gonna be built upon JavaFX. What I want to achieve is: I want to run this GUI when the user clicks a button, which means, invoke API that would do so, and keep it kind of isolated altought it's not a separate jar and I could inject spring dependencies in it, as well as exit the interface and kill any process started by it whenever I want to without killing the API itself. Could you help me?